# Highest DPS Melee weapon in terraria OTHER than Zenith

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I want to know what to use. I am post moon lord (with meowmere, terrablade, and horseman’s blade) on this particular account but I do not have zenith yet.

Comment: W/ meowmere, could attempt to get star wrath if needed

Comment: or i coupd go to mage build?

Comment: sorry i meant could in last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Star wrath's melee damage is 110 + 220 projectile damage as well as 16 use time(very fast), which makes it the highest DPS item other than the zenith, followed by meowmere(200 damage, 16 use time) then daybreak(150 damage, 16 use time).

Here are each of the items wiki pages:
[Star wrath](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wrath),
[Meowmere](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Meowmere),
[Daybreak](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Daybreak)

Comment: Ok thanks, ill use meowmere as i don't have starwrath yet.

Answer (score 0):

The highest dps is meowmere with projectile buffs and many target dummies

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/307415)

Comment: @n_plum Even if the formatting is poor, isn't this an attempted answer to the question?

Comment: This very much is an answer to the question (q: what's the highest DPS weapon a: Meowmere). But it *does* contradict the already accepted answer. Do you have any additional information on why this is the highest DPS, and not Star Wrath?

Comment: Felt more like a comment than an answer because of a lack of any additional information or backing to the claim.